# C# return struct reference from method

Tags: c#, struct, stack, return

In C++, returning a reference of an object allocated on the stack in a method, yields garbage values due to the fact, that the stack object is destroyed as soon the method leaves the scope. Given that in C# structs are allocated on the stack, would this yield garbage values as well?

```
struct Test
{
    //data
}

Test Foo()
{
    Test t1 = new Test();
    return t1;
}
```

Comment: `Given that in C# structs are allocated on the stack` This a false assumption, and hence any conclusions you draw from it aren't meaningful.

Comment: Structs in C# are pass-by-value. You are not returning a reference here, so no.

Comment: @Sweeper All methods that *aren't* marked as `ref` in their return type return a value, all methods that *are* return a reference.  The type is relevant, what matters is the signature of the method.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read this: http://mustoverride.com/ref-returns-and-locals/

In short, the C# Design team decided to disallow returning local variables by reference.

> **– Disallow returning local variables by reference. This is the**
>   solution that was chosen for C#. - To guarantee that a reference does
>   not outlive the referenced variable C# does not allow returning
>   references to local variables by reference. Interestingly, this is the
>   same approach used by Rust, although for slightly different reasons.
>   (Rust is a RAII language and actively destroys locals when exiting
>   scopes)

Even with the `ref` keyword, if you go ahead and try this:

```
public struct Test
{
    public int a;
}

public ref Test GetValueByRef()
{
    var test = new Test();
    return ref test;
}
```

You will see that the compiler errors out with the following:

> Cannot return local 'test' by reference because it is not a ref local

Comment: This wouldn't make sense either, since the local variable will go out of scope before it can be used. Such a thing is possible in C++, but it results in undefined behaviour and it is likely that the compiler notifies you of this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

keyword [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct) in C# describes a 'value type'. When you return a value type from a method, it creates new copy of it.
Beware of shallow copies, should that structure contain embedded containers (such as List<T>, ...)

Comment: Unless you use a ref return.

Comment: @Servy, particularly agree with you, but in this example he returns local variable. But, [the return value cannot be a local variable in the method that returns it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns)